# Magento2 change sort order of block using plugin

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order, plugin, sorting

I have used a plugin to add new template **at end of the page in Order view page** in admin but the issue is I cannot see it at end of the page, instead, it is showing inside **Address Information**, Please find below code of plugin I have used:

```
   <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info">
            <plugin name="commercepundit_dealerregistration-show_order_histiry" 
type="Commercepundit\Dealerregistration\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\SalesOrderViewInfo" 
sortOrder="99999" />
        </type>
```

It's showing like following right now:
[image: order view admin]

code of Plugin:

```
<?php
namespace Commercepundit\Dealerregistration\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml;

class SalesOrderViewInfo
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info $subject
     * @param string $result
     * @return string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function afterToHtml(
        \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $commentBlock = $subject->getLayout()->getBlock('order_status_history');
        if ($commentBlock !== false && $subject->getNameInLayout() == 'order_info') {
            $commentBlock->setOrder($subject->getOrder());
            $result = $result . $commentBlock->toHtml();
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: sortOrder tag does not sorting html content position

Comment: Please share  code of `ommercepundit\Dealerregistration\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\SalesOrderViewInfo`

Comment: added plugin code, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed behaviour of info.phtml file for order view i have override it with my module xml and changed order of order history and order totals section and my purpose was solved.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to add  template below order section then
You have to changes plugin class.

`Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info`

from  `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info`.

You have to create plugin on class  `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info`.

**You have  to changes**

> subject->getNameInLayout() == 'order_info'

**to**

> subject->getNameInLayout() == 'order_tab_info'

[`<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" name="order_tab_info" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/tab/info.phtml">`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml#L23)

### di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info">
        <plugin name="commercepundit_dealerregistration-show_order_histiry" 
                    type="Commercepundit\Dealerregistration\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\SalesOrderViewInfo" 
                    sortOrder="99999" />
    </type>
</config>
```

### PLugin Class

```
<?php

namespace Commercepundit\Dealerregistration\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml;


class SalesOrderViewInfo {

    public function afterToHtml(
    \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info $subject, $result
    ) {
        $commentBlock = $subject->getLayout()->getBlock('order_status_history');
        if ($commentBlock !== false && $subject->getNameInLayout() == 'order_info') {
            $commentBlock->setOrder($subject->getOrder());
            $result = $result . $commentBlock->toHtml();
        }

        //return $result.'testtest';
    return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is code i have used in sales_order_view.xml

<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="order_status_history" template="Commercepundit_Dealerregistration::order/view/statushistory.phtml" />

Comment: I have tried by changing to order_tab_info, now my template is not showing anywhere

Comment: did  you understand where you did the mistake ? You have the issue at condition

Comment: i have tried whatever you said but i cannot see my template in page by subject->getNameInLayout() == 'order_tab_info'

Comment: Okay.let me check

Comment: any success in above?

Comment: yes, i have got success

Comment: can you write here complete code? so i can get idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83203/discussion-between-bhargav-shastri-and-amit-bera).